# Output cout is exclamation mark. C++

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers

I've been told to write header file to the `main.cpp` which contains this:

```
OOP::array tab;

  for(int i = 0; i < rand()%10 + 1; ++i)
  {
    tab.push_back(new BaseClass("BaseClass 1"));
    tab.push_back(new BaseClass("BaseClass 2"));
    tab.push_back(new BaseClass("BaseClass 3"));
  }

  OOP::print_tab_el(tab); //prints tab using operator<< for its elements.
```

Class array is a container for smart pointers.
So I implemented `counted_ptr`, `BaseClass` and `array` (I used `std::vector` as a container) classes but when I invoke "`print_tab_el(tab)`" function, I get exclamation mark!

Seems like all of vector's items which are smart pointers contain "!" as name. I never put an "!" there.

Here's my header.

```
namespace OOP {

    class BaseClass
        {
            public:
                std::string name;

                BaseClass(std::string arg) {name=arg;}

                friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const BaseClass& ref)
                    {
                        os<<ref.name<<"\n"; //gives ! ???
                        return os;
                    }

        };



    class array
        {
            public:
                std::vector <counted_ptr<OOP::BaseClass> > myvec;

                void push_back( OOP::BaseClass *arg)
                    {
                       counted_ptr< OOP::BaseClass> tmp(arg);
                       myvec.push_back(tmp);

                    }

        };



    void print_tab_el(array arr)
         {

            std::vector <counted_ptr<OOP::BaseClass> >::iterator it;

            for (it=arr.myvec.begin();it!=arr.myvec.end();++it){
                 std::cout<<**it;
                }

         }

};
```

And this is program output:

```
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
and some more.
```

ADDED:

counted_ptr.cpp

```
#ifndef COUNTED_PTR_CPP
#define COUNTED_PTR_CPP

#include "counted_ptr.h"
#include <iostream>

/****************************************************************************/
template <class T>
counted_ptr<T>::counted_ptr(T* pointer):ptr(pointer)
    {
        refs.addRef();
    }
/****************************************************************************/

template <class T>
counted_ptr<T>::counted_ptr(const counted_ptr& ref):ptr(ref.ptr), refs(ref.refs+1) {}
/****************************************************************************/

template <class T>
counted_ptr<T>::~counted_ptr()
    {
        if (refs.takeRef()==0)
            delete ptr;
    }
/****************************************************************************/

template <class T>
T* counted_ptr<T>::operator->(){
    return ptr;
}
/****************************************************************************/

template <class T>
T& counted_ptr<T>::operator*(){
    return *ptr;
}
/****************************************************************************/

template <class T>
counted_ptr<T>& counted_ptr<T>::operator=(const counted_ptr<T>& rcpt_r){

    if (this!=&rcpt_r)
        {
            if (refs.takeRef()==0)
                delete ptr;

            ptr=rcpt_r.ptr;
            //refs=rcpt_r.refs+1;   
            refs=rcpt_r.refs;
            refs.addRef();      

        }

    return *this;
}
/****************************************************************************/
#endif
```

counted_ptr.h

```
#ifndef COUNTED_PTR_H
#define COUNTED_PTR_H

#include "reference.h"
template <class T>
class counted_ptr{

public:
    counted_ptr( T* pointer);
    counted_ptr(const counted_ptr& ref);
    ~counted_ptr();

    T* operator->();
    T& operator*();
    counted_ptr& operator=(const counted_ptr<T>& ref);


private:
    T *ptr;
    reference refs;

};

class testclass{};
#endif

#include "counted_ptr.cpp"
```

reference.cpp

```
#include "reference.h"
#include <iostream>

/****************************************************************************/
reference::reference():nr_of_references(0){}
/****************************************************************************/

reference::reference(const int value):nr_of_references(value){}

reference& reference::operator=(const int& ref)
    {
        nr_of_references=ref;
        return *this;
    }
/****************************************************************************/

reference::operator int()const
    {
        return nr_of_references;
    }
/****************************************************************************/

int reference::addRef()
    {
        return ++nr_of_references;
    }
/****************************************************************************/

int reference::takeRef()
    {
        return --nr_of_references;
    }
/****************************************************************************/
```

reference.h

```
class reference{
    public:
        reference();
        reference(const int value);
        //reference& operator=(const reference& ref);
        reference& operator=(const int& ref);
        operator int()const;

        int addRef();
        int takeRef();

    private:
        int nr_of_references;

};
```

Comment: I think we need to see a more complete example (in other words, what are you putting into `myvec`, for example?

Comment: Replacing `counted_ptr` with a C++11 `shared_ptr`, it works fine for me. So I'd say the issue is in `counted_ptr`, whatever that is.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you Mats, could you tell me more?

@David
counted_ptr is my smart pointer class based on counting references.

Comment: Why is `tmp` being pushed into `myvec` 2 times?

Comment: Already fixed that, it was my fault I copied it here 2x.

Comment: @user2672883 Here's confirmation your code [works](http://ideone.com/CYWrAH) if you use `shared_ptr`, almost conclusively showing the issue is in `counted_ptr`. (And it works with one `push_back` or two.)

Comment: I implemented counted_ptr to be minimalistic and working. Maybe you are right.
Could you guys take a look at this too.

Comment: @user2672883 Your edits don't seem to improve quality of the question.

Comment: Looks like you're hitting the default constructor of `BaseClass` that's not explicitly forbidden or declared somewhere.

Comment: If I add line to print on screen what is passed to the constructor it shows correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Every instance of `counted_ptr` has its own instance of `reference`. Each instance of `reference` has its own instance of `nr_of_references`. Although each `counter_ptr` manages `reference` properly, the problem is that the `counted_ptr` that only had a count of 1 will destruct the pointer when it goes out of scope, even after it was copied to a different `counted_ptr` instance.

Your `counted_ptr` needs to be redesigned so that all `counted_ptr`s to the same object also manipulate the same `reference`.

Comment: Which leads to the question what's the point of creating an array of pointers pointing to the same object?

Comment: That's correct, I can see it now.
I create object not using new operator but by simply calling constructor which allocates memory probably on heap.
That's why I loose objects when exiting push_back function.

Thank's a lot to all of you.